# mysql unicode support

Tags: mysql, unicode

I'm trying to store unicode strings in a MySQL database (MySQL version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.9 on an Ubuntu 10.04). This appears to work fine as long as I'm using the terminal to view the data. But, if I use MySQL Query Browser or Ruby on Rails to query the database all I get are garbage strings.

I've tried adding `default-character-set = utf8` and `character-set-server = utf8` to my `my.cnf` file and restarting MySQL, but that doesn't seem to help. My `database.yml` file has the line `encoding: utf8` but I'm guessing this is not the issue considering the fact that I can't view the data properly in MySQL Query Browser either.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: You should be able to set the client encoding on the client application/library.

Comment: That's what Rails does, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem with no help from the internet. The data was showing the correct data in terminal window only but both MySQL Query Browser and PHP were showing strange characters.

Finally I realized that the data in the database was NOT saved using the correct character set. So I updated the code from where I was inserting and updating with the addition `$link->set_charset('utf8');` where $link is the `mysqli` object.

Now the new data inserted is showing fine. I still don't understand why the MySQL Terminal was showing it correctly.

Anyway it works now!